# Proving the composition of an even function and an even function is even using the given definitions

Tags: calculus, functions, even-and-odd-functions

There are multiple answers to this question, but they use a slightly different version of what it means to be an odd function. I wanted to know what I did wrong in my process of trying to arrive at a solution.

> Defn: A function $f$ is **odd** if $f(x) = -f(-x)$ and a function is **even** if $f(x) = f(-x)$

Suppose $f$ is even and $g$ is even:

$$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) \\ = f(g(-x)) \ (\text{by definition of $g$ being even}) \\ = f(-g(-x)) \ (\text{by definition of $f$ being even}) \\ = f(-1 \cdot  g(-x)) $$

by properties of scalars with functions:

$$ = -f(g(-x)) \\ = -(f \circ g)(-x) $$

I know that this is wrong, and I feel it must be in the 4th line that I did something wrong, what is it that is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "by properties of scalars with functions" and the appearance of this $1$ make things a bit confusing. But the main issue is that you have an extra minus sign. So instead, you would like to write
$$
f(g(-x)) = f(-g(x)) = f(g(x)).
$$
The first equality uses that $g$ is odd, and the second that $f$ is even.

Comment: I messed up the set of functions that I meant to talk about. It was supposed to be two even functions.

Comment: Then you just have one minus sign to remove :)

Comment: how so?.....from line 2 to line 3 I am using the definition of an even function. i.e: letting $g(-x) = y$, I would have: $f(y) = f(-y)$ by definition, so how do I remove it?

Comment: You are going too far: $f(g(x)) = f(g(-x))$ since $g$ is even, and that is exactly saying that $f \circ g(x) = f \circ g (-x)$, i.e. that $f \circ g$ is even. In other word, for *any* function $f$, if $g$ is even, then $f \circ g$ is even.

Comment: Interesting....so I didn't even have to use the "eveness" of $f$?.....

Comment: Not for this one, because $g$ is *inside* the composition. When you look at $f \circ g$ at $-x$, you look at $g(-x)$ first, which is equal to $g(x)$. Therefore, what happens afterwards (composing by other functions) is irrelevant. But you may want to train and figure out what happens if $g$ is odd and $f$ even, and then if $g$ and $f$ are both odd.

Comment: Well I'd done the even, odd/case correctly and I guess to confirm the odd/odd case right now: $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(-g(-x))$, now this one does use the idea of the scalar. Thus: $f(-g(-x)) = -f(g(-x)) = -(f \circ g)(-x)$ which implies odd.

Comment: Great! A small piece of advice though: it is easier and more readable to start from $f(g(-x))$, and proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance